# "Attach" an integer to a string array, Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to have a hidden integer value attached to each string in this array.

```
String[] playerArray = {"Player1"};
```

For example, I want to be able to input "Player1, 44 28 63", and have those integers hidden, but able to act on it's own.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. What do you mean by having the integers hidden but able to act on their own? Also please post full code or snippets. That would help me understand the context of your question.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to add a 'Player' to the list, and be able to add integer values on the side, I don't have very much extra code, but I want to add random events that would change the integers or effected by them.

Comment: Create a data structure that can hold both a string and one or more integers, and then create an array of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create a Player object and have an array of those:

```
class Player {
   private String name; //?
   private int int1; //?

   public Player(String name, int int1) {
       this.name = name;
       this.in1 = int1;
   }
}

Player[] players = new Player[] {new Player("My String", 42);}
```

The good thing about this class is, that you can place code, methods, who acts on this data inside the class and so it helps your organize your code.